# NPE in Eclipse-Link AbstractSession.executeDeferredEvents(AbstractSession.java:1534) when using IndirectList

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, payara

From time to time I get a strange NPE in Eclipse-link AbstractSession.executeDeferredEvents(AbstractSession.java:1534). It does not happen very often and so far I was not able to reproduce this.

As my investigation has shown it happens always when I do operations on an IndirectList. The failing line has something like `entity.getAttributes().isEmpty()`.

I have the list of items defines like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH }, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(
    schema = EntityConstants.SCHEMA,
    name = EntityConstants.TABLE_PREFIX + EntityConstants.TABLE_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, //
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "entityid") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "attributeid") }) //
@FieldPrivilege(PRIV_UPDATE_ATTRIBUTES)
private List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
```

What I use:

- Payara: 5.2022.3
- Payara included eclipse-link: 2.7.9.payara-p2
- Java: zulu11.52.13-ca-jdk11.0.13
- Postgres: 11

The stacktrace:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeDeferredEvents(AbstractSession.java:1534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3005)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1880)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.buildDelegate(IndirectList.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.getDelegate(IndirectList.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.isEmpty(IndirectList.java:542)
    at com.xxx.entities.interfaces.AttributeCapable.getAttribute(AttributeCapable.java:22)
```

Comment: How are you accessing this list? - specifically the where and when. Make sure you aren't concurrently accessing entities from the same context; EntityManager instances and the artifacts read from them (especially lazy lists) are not thread safe which I believe this error is likely related to.

Comment: This list is accessed mostly concurrently thats true. I have a framwork which has timers running which perform actions in new threads and those actions need to read the data. So I can not make sure the same data is not read by multiple threads at the same time. The thing is that this is the same for years and I seem to get this problem only recently.
Also it is not only happening with this list, other obejcts with lazy references seem to have the same problem from time to time.

Comment: All indirection should have the issue - entities read from a EntityManager are not thread safe. If you want to cache/access data on entities asynchronously, make sure all data required is fetched upfront, with the read with Join fetch in the query, query properties and fetch/load graphs, or even by manually accessing the properties on returned entities before returning them. As for it only occurring now - I'm sure there have been many changes that might make concurrency more of an issue. You can (and I can help) look into it, but it isn't a supported pattern; it needs app level locking